# Sublime: Shortcut Key to Confirm Replace All?

Tags: sublimetext2

After I hit **Ctrl**-H and enter my search/replace terms, is there another key combination I can hit to actually execute that command, without having to use the mouse to press the **Replace All** button?

I am not a mouse guy, and would prefer to do it from the keyboard.

Thanks

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The shortcut for replace all should be "ctrl+alt+enter"

Here it is in the Keybinding JSON.

```
{ "keys": ["ctrl+alt+enter"], "command": "replace_all", "args": {"close_panel": true},
     "context": [{"key": "panel", "operand": "replace"}, {"key": "panel_has_focus"}]
},
```

You can see the full list of key bindings / shortcuts by going to the Preferences Menu then Keybindings -> Keybindings - Default . It will show a json file full of all the shortcuts.

To create your own shortcut by going to the Preferences Menu then Keybindings -> Keybindings - User, just add your own entry to the json file, in the same format as the json file openend by doing the above.

Comment: Thanks for that. Do you know of a way to replace all but leave the replace panel visible, rather than closing it after the action?

Comment: Change {"close_panel": true} to {"close_panel": false}. :)

Comment: Sorry to revive this so many years later, but I've just stumbled across this, as I had the same question. I have the same keybinding for `replace_all`, but pressing that key combination in the find-and-replace window doesn't work for me. Any idea what might be conflicting/stopping it from working? I also have SublimeLinter installed... could that be it? If so, how might I make this key binding take precedence?